# How can a parent component communicate with a child component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is what I have:

```
<div id='vnav-container'>
    <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" v-on:keyup="search" class="vnav-input">
    <menu :items="menu"></menu>
</div>
```

The `outer` component contains a `search-input` and a `menu` component.

When the user performs a search on the `outer` component, I need to call a method on the `menu` component, or emit an event, or whatever, as long as I can communicate to the `menu` component saying it should filter itself based on the new criteria.

I've read somewhere that *calling methods on child components is discouraged* and that I should use events. I'm looking at the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events) right now, but I can only see an example of a child talking to a parent, not the other way around.

**How can I communicate to the menu component as the search criteria changes?**

**EDIT**

According to some blog posts, there used to be a `$broadcast` method intended to talk to child components but the documentation about that just vanished. This used to be the URL: http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-broadcast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is "[props down, events up](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Composing-Components)". Data flows from parents to child components via props, so you could add a prop to the menu, maybe:

```
<menu :items="menu" :searchTerm="searchTerm"></menu>
```

The filtering system (I'm guessing it's a computed?) would be based on `searchTerm`, and would update whenever it changed.

When a system of components becomes large, passing the data through many layers of components can be cumbersome, and some sort of central store is generally used.

Comment: That was clarifying @Roy. I'm coming from React. Question: Will <menu/> be automatically rerendered as a result of `searchTerm` changing?

Comment: Yes, props are reactive just like data items, so Vue will rerender as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$broadcast` was deprecated in 2.x.  See the [Migration guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-deprecated) for some ideas on replacing the functionality (which includes event hubs or [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can create the kind of simple store for that.

First off, let's create the new file called *searchStore.js* it would just VanillaJS Object

```
export default {

    searchStore: { 
        searchTerm: '' 
    } 


}
```

And then in files where you are using this store you have to import it

```
import Store from '../storedir/searchStore'
```

And then in your component, where you want to filter data, you should, create new data object

```
data() {
   return {
      shared: Store.searchStore
   }
}
```

About methods - you could put method in your store, like this

```
doFilter(param) {
  // Do some logic here
}
```

And then again in your component, you can call it like this

```
methods: {
   search() {
      Store.doFilter(param)
   }
}
```

And you are right $broadcast and $dispatch are deprecated in VueJS 2.0